# compare elements in list to every other element in same list

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7. If I have list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want a new listthat contains something like

```
b = [a[0]*a[1], a[0]*a[2], a[0]*a[3], a[0]*a[4], a[1]*a[0], a[1]*a[2], ... ]
```

where each element is mulitplied by the other elements but do not muliply with themselves. my intuition tells me to do the following (in a very non pythonic way):

```
 b = []
 for i in range(0,len(a)):
     b.append(a[i]*a[i+1])
```

but this is only performing the task for the first element in the list

Comment: I think you could use `itertools`: `[x * y for x, y in itertools.combinations(a, 2)]`

Comment: import itertools from itertools import combinations [x * y for x, y in itertools.combinations(a, 2)] yields error message 'module' object is not iterable

Comment: I'm not sure vaultah. The output implies that combination s will be repeated...  `a[0]*a[1]` and `a[1]*a[0]` which `itertools.combinations` would not give you...

Comment: Yes, but what's the point of keeping duplicate products? Also, this was just a guess.

Comment: I don't know, there could be many. Or it could have been a typo. I think it's a reasonable guess, but clarification on that point is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the multiplication using a *list comprehension* and `enumerate` which allows to skip self-multiplications with a *filter*:

```
prods = [x*y for i, x in enumerate(a) for j, y in enumerate(a) if i!=j]
print(prods)
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 8, 10, 3, 6, 12, 15, 4, 8, 12, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Comment: yes thank you so much this is the pythonic answer i was looking for

Comment: Just a side note, it's often prettier and easier to read if you write it on multiple lines: https://pastebin.com/u1nfUqLf

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen If you find yourself having to split up list comprehensions onto multiple lines, you probably shouldn’t use list comprehensions there.

Comment: @poke Well that's just straight up nonsens, only your opinion. The accepted answer is a good example of that: imo it looks horrible on one line, but clean and pretty on multiple lines. [Here's another example](https://pastebin.com/ZJ6sAPDV) from the top of my head. Makes sense to use list comprehension, and makes sense to split it on multiple lines. First line: what you want. Second line: where do you want it from. Third line: condition.